# Font Awesome Reusable Widget for Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

I have a question about a reusable font awesome widget for Flutter that I am trying to create.

I am getting an error in Android Studio for Windows that, "The method 'FaIcon' isn't defined for the type 'IconContent'."

Below is how I set up the reusable widget.  I found this advice but not sure how to implement: "Use the FaIcon Widget + FontAwesomeIcons class for the IconData"

https://gist.github.com/countrymusicfy/3c5aa155063b49bf5d07e89241bc637b

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Import is missing - `import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing import statement

You should include both in pubspec.yaml file and in your dart file.

Add import statement on your dart file

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
```

Add dependecy on your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
```